# Webpack 2 chunk name contains undefined

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

[image: Chunk name contains undefined]

I'm trying to upgrade to Webpack 2. I used code-splitting with on-demand loading (using require.ensure) with Webpack 1 successfully. However, with webpack 2 the filename of the chunk contains an "undefined" which causes it to 404.

webpack.config.js

```
{
  entry: {
    'main': 'index.ts',
    'vendor': 'vendor.ts'
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[hash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist')
  },

  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      //proxy info
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      helper.root('src'),
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
  },

  cache: false,
  devtool: 'cheap-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
       minChunks: function (module) {
        return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ 
      name: 'manifest'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename:'[name]-[hash].css',
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      inject: true
    }),
    new ngAnnotatePlugin({
      add: true
    }),
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
      assetNameRegExp: /\.optimize\.css$/g,
      cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
      cssProcessorOptions: { discardComments: { removeAll: true } },
      canPrint: true
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin(require('../tslint.json')),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      configFile: './.htmlhintrc'
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      configFile: './.sass-lint.yml'
    }),
    new DashboardPlugin(),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\\\/]locale$/, /^\.\/(de|en|fr|ko|ja|zh-cn)$/)
  ],
  module: {
    rules: loaders
  },
}
```

I've already tried different variations to chunkFilename (using [name], [id], [chunkhash] in many combinations). None of them work. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I had `__webpack_public_path` set to a variable that was undefined.